# Deployment failed with error : login failed for user 'xx'

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-process, build-automation, msbuild-4.0

The deployment of the build in TFS failed within 10 seconds with the following error.
**Deployment fail with error: Login failed for user 'XX'**
Any help
Thanks, suren

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you might need to give more information that this?

Answer (score 0):

The build server agent may have an expired password or the login is incorrect.